# Is acceleration frame dependent or absolute?

Tags: general-relativity, classical-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration, charge

as relative acceleration changes from different point of views so property of things in frame should also change but stationary charge do not radiate E.M waves as seen from accelerating frame i.e. acceleration is something which is absolute because of inertia?

It looks like either i got a misconception or i am lacking something ..you are reading  it still !! your answers will be precious

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  You should reformulate the question to help attract people to answer it.

Comment: Probably related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_a_charge_in_a_gravitational_field

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the definition of frame. If by "frame" you mean inertial frame then yes acceleration is absolute. But we often still talk of accelerated frames of reference, so acceleration is relative in that more expansive definition of frame.

However physics does not look the same in an accelerated frame of reference as it does in all inertial frames. In classical mechanics there are pseudoforces (like centrifugal force), in electricity and magnetism (as you mentioned), "stationary" particles will radiate , and in quantum field theory, the temperature increases.

Answer (score 0):

Quantities whose value depends on the particular frame chosen for describing setup and observational findings are called "unphysical" or "ficticious".

This applies to [coordinate acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration) in general; and for choices of [rotating frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_of_reference#Non-inertial_frames) specificly to [azimuthal acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration), [centrifugal acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force#Acceleration) and [Coriolis acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force#Accelerations).

In contrast, accelerations which are frame-independent are

- "the (intrinsic, absolute, physical) acceleration" of an (ideally point-like) participant which can be expressed for instance through the (explicitly frame-independent) values of [spacetime intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Spacetime_interval) between the pairs of events that constitute the trajectory, and
- suitably frame-independently defined "relative (radial) acceleration" of one particular participant with respect to a particular other.